# Map inside a return in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm learning React doing a Test app, but i have problems at the moment of know the correct answer inside the .map of the return part, here is my code:

```
const Question = (props) => {
/*This part randomize the order of answers*/
let render_order = questions[props.level][props.option][1]
const correct = render_order[0]
render_order = render_order.sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5 })

return (
    <div class='question'>
        <div class='real_question'>
            {questions[props.level][props.option][0]}
        </div>
        {render_order.map(a => {
            return <div class='option'> {a} {correct}</div>
        })}
    </div>
)}
```

where 'correct' is always the correct answer; but at the moment of render 'correct' inside the .map, this become another answer of the question.

Comment: Can you share the sample data of `render_order` so that it will be easy to analyze

Comment: @Thinker Of course: `render_order` is like [2, 5, 4, 3, 7], where 2 is the correct answer, after become something like [4, 5, 2, 7, 3], ready to render (this works fine when console log the 'disorder' list and the correct answer)

Comment: this is what u want? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-w14jo?file=/index.js

Comment: Almost! what i exactly want is add an different style/functionality to the correct answer; for example, green background to the correct answer, red background else

Comment: add a class to the `correct` div and insert style

Comment: Yep! But i dont know how to diferenciate between the correct div, and the worngs inside the .map :c, can you show me in code how to do it pls?

Comment: please refer my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const Question = (props) => {
  /*This part randomize the order of answers*/
  let render_order = [2, 5, 4, 3, 7];
  const correct = render_order[0];
  render_order = render_order.sort(function () {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
  });

  return (
    <div class="question">
      Answer: {correct}{" "}
      {render_order.map((a, index) => {
        return (
          <div className={`option ${a === correct ? "correct" : ""}`}>
            `Question {index + 1}: ${a}`
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};


class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Question />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/qfsjczda/1/

Happy coding !!!

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand the render_order is a list of options for the question.

render_order.map will map each element in your list to a jsx element which will be rendered.

> ```
> {render_order.map(a => {
>             return <div className='option'> {a} {correct}</div>
> })}
> ```

In the above snippet for each option you may also be appending the correct option

A possible update would be to only render the option and not the correct answer-

> ```
> {render_order.map(a => {
>             return <div className='option'> {a}</div>
> })}
> ```

EDIT- To change the color when option matches the correct answer

> ```
> {render_order.map(a => {
>             return <div className={`option ${a===correct && 'correct'}`} > {a}</div>;
> })}
> ```

In your CSS  add this class

.correct {

background-color:green;

}

Comment: Almost! but i need the information of the correct answer inside the .map; for example, i want to change the background color to green just if i click in the correct answer

Comment: I have edited my answer to add your change

Answer (score 0):

I think your `{correct}` is getting repeated unnecesarily.

```
<div class='question'>
        <div class='real_question'>
            {questions[props.level][props.option][0]}
        </div>
        {render_order.map(a => {
            return <div class='option'> {a}</div>
        })}
        {correct}
 </div>
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Not exactly; i need the correct information inside the map, for example, i wanna background color green the div of just the correct option

Answer (score 0):

Try adding key property to every item in the list